# HTML Table in VB.Net back end code

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a table that I have created in the VB.net code behind.  I have a connection to a database and it returns records to put into my html table.  What I'm having issues with is I want to have 5 cells per row and an unlimited amount of rows.  Everytime I try and do something that only has the 5 cells per row it's returning something that I don't need.  Please help!! Here is the code that I'm using.

```
Protected Sub LoadProducts()
    Dim con5 As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd5 As New SqlCommand
    Dim index As Integer = 0

    con5.ConnectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ConnectionString")
    con5.Open()
    cmd5.Connection = con5
    cmd5.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd5.CommandText = "ProductTypesSearch"

    Dim dt1 As New DataSet
    cmd5.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("ProductID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 1
    cmd5.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("CollectionID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 2

    Dim da1 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd5)
    da1.Fill(dt1)
    Dim cell As HtmlTableCell
    Dim row As HtmlTableRow
    Dim table1 As New HtmlTable
    row = New HtmlTableRow()
    Dim numells As Integer = 6

    dv = New DataView(dt1.Tables(0))
    Dim tablestring = ""
    If dv.Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each dr As DataRowView In dv
            Dim crossover As String = dr("CrossoverID").ToString()
            Dim picid As String = dr("Description").ToString()
            Dim picdescrip As String = dr("DesignColor").ToString()
            cell = New HtmlTableCell()

            For j As Integer = 0 To 5
                cell.InnerHtml = "<table width-'100%'>"
                cell.InnerHtml += "<tr><td><div class='product'><td><a href='ProductBreakdown2.aspx?p=" + crossover + "'</a>"
                cell.InnerHtml += "<div class='product'><img src='Images/WebsiteProductImages/" + picid + ".png' width='100' height='100'>"
                cell.InnerHtml += "<div class = 'test'>" + picdescrip
                cell.InnerHtml += "</td></tr></div></div></table>"

                row.Cells.Add(cell)
            Next

            table1.Rows.Add(row)
        Next

        Me.Controls.Add(table1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping one extra time, because of this logic:

```
Dim numells As Integer = 6

For j As Integer = 0 To numells - 1
```

That equates to `For j As Integer = 0 To 5`, which is 6 iterations instead of 5.

Change your declaration to this:

```
Dim numells As Integer = 5
```

Now your `For` loop will iterate 5 times instead of 6.

UPDATE:

Your code is not creating a new row on each iteration through the `For Each dr As DataRowView In dv` loop. You need to create a new `HtmlTableRow` object each time, like this:

```
For Each dr As DataRowView In dv
    ' Each time through this loop we need a new row object
    row = New HtmlTableRow()

    Dim crossover As String = dr("CrossoverID").ToString()
    Dim picid As String = dr("Description").ToString()
    Dim picdescrip As String = dr("DesignColor").ToString()
    cell = New HtmlTableCell()

    For j As Integer = 0 To 5
        cell.InnerHtml = "<table width-'100%'>"
        cell.InnerHtml += "<tr><td><div class='product'><td><a href='ProductBreakdown2.aspx?p=" + crossover + "'</a>"
        cell.InnerHtml += "<div class='product'><img src='Images/WebsiteProductImages/" + picid + ".png' width='100' height='100'>"
        cell.InnerHtml += "<div class = 'test'>" + picdescrip
        cell.InnerHtml += "</td></tr></div></div></table>"

        row.Cells.Add(cell)
    Next

    table1.Rows.Add(row)
Next
```

Comment: This is still showing all the returned records on one row.  I want to have 5 cells on each row with unlimited rows.  I changed the integer to equal 5, but it still has everything showing up on one row.  It returns ten records and all ten records are appearing on that one row.

Comment: This is happening because are never creating a new row, once you get through the looping of the cells and you are not adding the row to the table (`table1`), because it is commented out. Could you please update your code in the question and remove all commented out code?

Comment: Here is the updated code with all the comments taken out.  This is still not displaying correctly though.

Comment: See the `UPDATE:` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here that might be causing problems.  First, why are you putting `table`/`tr`/`td` tags into the `InnerHtml` of the `Cell` object?  The idea behind the ASP.Net `Table` is that it will generate all of the necessary HTML for you.

Second, you aren't reinitializing the `row` variable after you add it to the `table` object.  (You also aren't reinitializing the `cell` variable after you add it to the `row` object, but that has no impact because of how the `InnerHtml` property is being changed in each loop iteration.)

To make this work, move `row = New HtmlTableRow()` down to be the first line after `For Each dr As DataRowView In dv` so that a new object is created on each iteration.

```
....
Dim table1 As New HtmlTable
Dim numells As Integer = 6

dv = New DataView(dt1.Tables(0))
Dim tablestring = ""
If dv.Table.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    For Each dr As DataRowView In dv
        row = New HtmlTableRow()
        Dim crossover As String = dr("CrossoverID").ToString()
        ....
```

Also, as mentioned by Karl Anderson, the loop `For j As Integer = 0 To 5` actually gives you 6 iterations (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5).  This would give you 6 cells instead of the 5 that you want.

Comment: Ok moving that did help and now it is creating six items per row, but it is placing the exact same items in each row instead of placing 5 unique records on the first row and then 5 uniques records on the next row, etc.

Comment: That's because the loop that populates the `cell` object does the exact same thing in each iteration.  It sounds like you want to change the rows in a data set to cells in a table, which is a whole different problem than you've solved with the code in question.

Comment: I'm kind of new to this so that's why I have so many questions.  If I change this from rows in a data set to cells in a table how do I retrieve my values and how exactly do I accomplish this?  I've never had to do create a table in the back end code like this so I'm trying to piece together how to do this.  Thanks so much for all your help and suggestion!!

Comment: Well, I think we've solved your original question.  If you get a little further and get stuck, do some more research and then ask a different question.  You're certainly not the first one to have the issue, and probably not the first one to ask about it.